# Get Links with simple html dom

Tags: php, html, find, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get links from the site.

"http://www.perfumesclub.com/es/perfume/mujer/c/"

For this use "user-agent" in simple html Sun.

But I get this error ..

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on string in C:\Users\Desktop\www\funciones.php on line 448
```

This is my code:

Thanks^^

```
$url = 'http://www.perfumesclub.com/es/perfume/mujer/c/';

$option = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
        )
);
$context = stream_context_create($option);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);


$perfumes = $html->find('.imageProductDouble');  --> this is line 448

foreach($perfumes as $perfume) {
            // Get the link

            $enlaces = "http://www.perfumesclub.com" . $perfume->href;
            echo $enlaces . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your file_get_contents in str_get_html function

```
// method 1
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load( file_get_contents ($url, false, $context) );
// or method 2
$html = str_get_html( file_get_contents ($url, false, $context) );
```

you're creating a new dom and assigning it to the variable $html, than reading the url returning the string and setting it to $html, thus overwriting your simple_html_dom instance, so when your invoking the find method you have a string instead of an object.

Comment: It is true. I had not occurred to me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

`$html` is a string after the call to `file_get_contents`. Try

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

OR use

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
```

after the call to `file_get_contents`.